# jQuery mobile image array. How to add another div with image array?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, swipe

```
var aryimageSet1=["img1.jpg","img2.jpg"];
var aryimageSet2=["img3.jpg","img4.jpg"];

/..some code../

$objImage = $("#div1")
$ary = aryimageSet1;
```

When I run this code, and then swipe on the tablet over that div1 space, it switching my images like it suppose to.

Can anyone tell me, how can I declare another div2 in jQuery?

```
$objImage = $("#div2")
$ary = aryimageSet2;
```

Im using jQuery mobile. When I finger swap over certain #div on the tablet, it will loop images (exp. img1.jpg - img2.jpg). What I'm trying to do now is I made another #div in the HTML and I need to add another image array. And I not sure how. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', '.swipe', function (e) {
    switch(e.target.id) {
        case "swipe1_id":
            $objImage = $("#div1")
            $ary = aryimageSet1;
           break;
         case "swipe2_id":
            $objImage = $("#div2")
            $ary = aryimageSet2;
           break;
     }
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="swipe1_id" class="swipe"></div>
<div id="swipe2_id" class="swipe"></div>
```

Solved the problem on my own whew :) Not sure if its perfect but it works for me. I am sorry if I wasn't clear on my question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a little bit more? what is the code `$objImage = $("#div2)
$ary = aryimageSet2;` suppose to mean? (you are missing a double quote after `"#div2->"<-`)

Comment: This code is just an example, what I need to add in the jQuery file, for my second div to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method:

```
$div2 = $("#div1").clone().attr('id', 'div2');
```

then loop through the image url array and set the image attr's on the new div:

```
$div2.find('img').each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr('src', aryimageSet2[index]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. What it does now, when I swipe from any div's (#div1 & #div2), both of them looping through the same "aryimageSet1" array images. I need #div2 to loop from "aryimagesSet2".

Comment: I can't find any issues in my example, it works when I run it locally in the scenario I think you are describing. Try making sure the second image array variable is properly set (maybe avoid using the same variable name)

Comment: Ok, I need $objImage = $("#div1") $ary = aryimageSet1; and $objImage = $("#div2") $ary = aryimageSet2; put them together. If I'll put them in this order browser will read only #div2. And on swipe both of them will loop only #div2. This is exactly same thing I get when I trying to use your advice above. What I need is on swipe #div1 looping - aryimageSet1 and when I swipe #div2 it will loop - aryimageSet2 images.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $newDiv = $('<div id="div2">');
```

That creates a new div element. You can then manipulate that element and insert it into the DOM (or do whatever you planned on using this for).